# Hiding 3rd level menu from sidebar, but displaying elsewhere. Possible? - D7

Tags: routes

I have a 3 level menu structure in the sidebar. I would like to add a set of submenus for one of the Second level menu items, but would this time like to hide it's children from the sidebar. Instead, I would like this menu to be displayed in the main content area. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

So just to clarify, some 3rd level menus I would like to display in the sidebar, but other 3rd level menus I would like to hide from the sidebar, but instead display in the main content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The level of control you need can be achieved using [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module:

> So… have you ever used the Main and Secondary menu links feature on your theme and wondered “how the hell do I display any menu items deeper than that?”
>
> Well, that’s what this module does. It provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu. And more!
>
> So if you’re only using your theme’s Main menu links feature, you can add and configure a “Main menu (levels 2+)” block. That block would appear once you were on one of the Main menu’s pages and would show the menu tree for the 2nd level (and deeper) of your Main menu and would expand as you traversed down the tree. You can also limit the depth of the menu’s tree (e.g. “Main menu (levels 2-3)”) and/or expand all the child sub-menus (e.g. “Main menu (expanded levels 2+)”).
>
> Pretty simple, eh?

Comment: Thank you @Molot
How would I go about hiding a level from the menu displayed in the sidebar?

Comment: @user19417 you can select both start level and default depth, to hide everything above and below. So on sidebar you need to set maximum depth to 2, and "elsewhere" starting element to 3rd level one.

Comment: I would like to extract 2 menu blocks from my existing menu. I have managed to do so for one, but not the other.

What I am trying to do is extract the 3rd level menu items. There are 2 x 3rd level menu items. What do I need to do in order to get the second one working? I have tried setting the fixed parent item to the 3rd and 4th levels but neither works. What am I doing wrong?

@Molot